# "Flexible" Responsive table using divs. Where a full column stretches if able

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, tabular

Well Consider I have a table with 3 columns. "Normally" each column should take 1/3rd of the page. However if one of the column's data gets too large, and the other columns have extra space it should "flex", and the column should occupy the remaining space.

However it should still be a "table": as in column & row borders need to align.

When using naive flex boxes I tried both a row and column first approach. However both have the problem that the "inner" flexbox might  stretch, but that information is lost on the other flex boxes.

I've tried to solve it below using both methods: but as you can see it's not working:

```css
 .bordered{
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: black;
      border-style: solid;
    }
    
    .main {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .cell {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      max-width: 75%;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="main bordered">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="cell bordered">
               first
           </div>
           <div class="cell bordered">
               second
           </div>
           <div class="cell bordered">
               third
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="cell bordered">
               first
           </div>
           <div class="cell bordered">
               This is text that will increase the width of the cell.
           </div>
           <div class="cell bordered">
               third
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="cell bordered">
               first
           </div>
           <div class="cell bordered">
               This is text that will increase the width of the cell. Not only that, but due to the amount of text it also increases the height of a row. This isn't a problem with this setup. But had we chosen to use a column-first approach this cell would destroy any "row" layout.
           </div>
           <div class="cell bordered">
               third
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Can this be done? Or should I give up on this?

Comment: Flexbox is *not* a suitable replacement for a `table` in most cases. There is NO method of aligning column widths in rows as you seem to require. Why not use an actual `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is probably ***not*** the best-suited solution for this. I would recommend looking to use [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). There are many ways to accomplish this, but here's a start.

Use a 3 column, 3 row grid, with auto width cells (using an optional `min-width` to preserve some space).

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

.bordered {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

.cell {
  grid-column-end: span 1;
}

.cell:nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.cell:nth-child(3n+2) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.cell:nth-child(3n+3) {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main bordered">
  <div class="cell bordered">
    first
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    second
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    third
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    first
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    This is text that will increase the width of the cell.
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    third
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    first
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    This is text that will increase the width of the cell. Not only that, but due to the amount of text it also increases the height of a row. This isn't a problem with this setup. But had we chosen to use a column-first approach this cell would destroy any
    "row" layout.
  </div>
  <div class="cell bordered">
    third
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how well is this supported on IE though?

Comment: The example above could be made to work in IE using the `-ms` prefixes/properties. this could be done manually, or ideally using a tool like Autoprefixer.

Comment: Well it's not for myself, but consumers of the website are typically computer illiterate people. So I expect lots of IE people, and telling them to set a property will be more than they can handle. I'm going to accept this as it is a perfect solution, but if someone has an imperfect one for IE I'd still like that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Are you expecting the consumers to create the HTML layout and CSS?

Comment: No I expect a sizeable base of my users to just use IE 9-11. And the website has as medium important design parameter that it should still *work* on IE; without requiring the users to do anything.

Comment: Right, so if you're doing the HTML/CSS you can add the necessary prefixes/CSS to support IE.